# avoid type casting on promise return

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-promise, typescript-typings

I have an action that do some calculations with an API response as follows

```
try {
  const data = await FooService.request();

  someCalculation1(data as FooServiceData);
  someCalculation2(data as FooServiceData);
  someCalculation3(data as FooServiceData);
  someCalculation4(data as FooServiceData);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

The point is that is pretty anoying, and not so readable, keep re-typing `as SomeServiceData` every time, but I believe need to do this since my `FooService.request` has this kind of implementation

```
request(): Promise<SomeServiceData | Error> {
  return callApi()
    .then(res => {
      return res as SomeServiceData;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return Error("Some error")
    })

}
```

As the function can return each `SomeServiceData` or `Error` it forces me to cast the type. But the point is that `data` will never be of type `Error` since if it be, it will not be, the error will be thrown and `err` will be the type `Error`. But I cant figure out how can I avoid that casting.

I think to change the service form the `Promise` format to `async`/`await` format, but I don't believe it will change the behavior at all.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, you could type the `data` itself instead of the parameter expressions:

```
const data = (await FooService.request()) as FooServiceData;
```

But it sounds like you want to catch in the *caller* of `request`, not in `request` itself - leave off the `.catch` inside `request` so that when there's an error, the caller will handle it. (Your current code results in `data` being an actual Error, since the `.catch` results in a Promise that resolves to the returned error.)

Try:

```
try {
  const data = await FooService.request();

  someCalculation1(data);
  // ...
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

```
request() {
  return callApi()
    .then(res => {
      return res as SomeServiceData;
    });
}
```

or even

```
request() {
  return callApi() as Promise<SomeServiceData>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the point is that data will never be of type Error since if it be, it will not be, the error will be thrown and err will be the type Error.

This is incorrect.  The promise could resolve to an `Error` object in your implementation because you are catching the API error in `request()` and returning a `new Error` when that happens.  When you `catch`, you are preventing the error from being thrown.

Rather than a `try/catch` block in your action, you would need to check the type of `data` to distinguish between `Error` and `SomeServiceData`.  You can use `if ( data instanceof Error )` as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) and within the two branches typescript knows that it can only be that type.

```
  const data = await FooService.request();

  if ( data instanceof Error ) {
    // data is Error
    console.log(data.message); 
  } else {
    // data is SomeServiceData
    someCalculation1(data);
  }
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the `try/catch` block in your action then you need to change `FooService.request()` so that it throws an error instead of catching it.  Basically you only need to catch the error in one of the two places.  Once it's caught it will not be thrown again.

```
const FooService = {
  async request(): Promise<SomeServiceData> {
    return await callApi() as SomeServiceData;
  }
}
```

Now the promise can only resolve to `SomeServiceData`.